# is there any php redis client support persistent connection?

Tags: php, redis, persistent

As the title, I'm looking for a php Redis client that support persistent connection, because my web application receives a lot of requests(each request, it'll put an item in to Redis queue) and I want to avoid create new connection every request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is supported but you should definitely look at Predis and Rediska, this two (especially Predis AFAIK) are the best PHP Redis clients available.

Comment: thank you antirez, I've never tried Predis before, it seem support persistent connection, I believe that a C implementation as php-module should be faster, but i'll try them and take a comparison.

Comment: The concern is whether Predis supports persistent connections since it's a purely PHP implementation and not a C-based extension. 
According to the maintainer, Predis does support persistent connections if your PHP processes are configured to stay resident. This is typical on a serious production PHP + Apache setup, though your particular install may vary and may require some configuration. The [Predis FAQ](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/master/FAQ.markdown) points out that connections are persistent when Predis is persistent and PHP processes are recycled for requests.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't yet tested Predis. I am trying the C extension first since Predis looks to be built in using a very verbose style. I also do not like relying on PHP's autoload mechanisms.

Comment: phpredis is allegedly quite a lot faster than predis

Answer (score 4):

[PhpRedis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) currently supports persistent connections. Using PHP 7.0 and PhpRedis 3.0, making a persistent connection with [`pconnect()`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#pconnect-popen) like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $result = $redis->pconnect('127.0.0.1'); 
    $redis->set("iterator",$i);
    $response=$redis->get("iterator");
    $redis->close();
    unset($redis);
}
```

is about 10 times faster (9.6 msec vs 0.83 msec per connection) than [`connect()`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#connect-open):

```
for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $result = $redis->connect('127.0.0.1'); 
    $redis->set("iterator",$i);
    $response=$redis->get("iterator");
    $redis->close();
    unset($redis); 
}
```

Note: "This feature is not available in threaded versions". (I'm running under IIS on Windows, so I run the NTS version.)

Answer (score 2):

Predis supports persistent connection. you just need to add persistent paramater as 1.

you can use the code below

```
$client = new Predis\Client(array(
   'scheme'    => 'tcp',
   'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
   'port'      => 6379,
   'database'  => 15,
   'persistent'=> 1
));
```

instead of

```
$client = new Predis\Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?database=15');
```

you can find more parameters for the connection here : 
 https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Predis supports persistent connections using it's `PhpiredisStreamConnection` with the `persistent=1` flag syntax since v0.8.0:

```
<?php
$client = new Predis\Client('tcp://127.0.0.1?persistent=1', array(
    'connections' => array(
        'tcp'  => 'Predis\Connection\PhpiredisStreamConnection',
        'unix' => 'Predis\Connection\PhpiredisStreamConnection',
    ),
);
```

Comment: I added persistant=1 with PhpiredisStreamConnection and looks like I still get the same TIME_WAIT socket after all.

Answer (score -2):

PHP-Redis supports persistent connections since it uses a php extension written in C which gives it a mechanism for sharing connections between requests. Look at the documentation on [popen and pconnect](https://github.com/owlient/phpredis).

Predis *cannot* support persistent connections because it is 100% PHP and PHP shares nothing between each request.

Comment: According to the Predis author, this answer is incorrect. He claims that PHP requests may share information when the PHP processes are configured to stay resident between requests, as is the case with many implementations.

Comment: Agreed, this answer is wrong.  `popen()` is the wrong type of resource anyway (p == piped process).  `pconnect()` is fully capable of supporting Zend's internal "xport" resource handling which allows persistent connections to be maintained.  Predis itself uses [stream_socket_client()](http://php.net/stream_socket_client), with an optional `STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT` flag.  When the PHP process is maintained by something like Apache with a pool of backend processes/threads, those persistent connections survive within the lifetime of the backend.